# How can I attach angled beams to a post?

Tags: deck, load-bearing, beam

I'm designing a deck with 3-2x10 beams supported by 6x6 posts. I know when the beams go straight across the posts I can use any number of brackets designed for that purpose, like Simpson AC4 (or AC6, in my case):

[image]

But what about at corners where the beam isn't straight? I have 45 degree corners in my design:

[image]

I also have one place where one beam intersects another at a 45 degree angle:

[image]

What's a proper way to make these connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of ways to attach beams to posts, and you don't necessarily need purpose-built brackets. Miter your beams so that they come together at an appropriate bisection of the post top, and use whatever means is convenient to keep them positioned... dowels, angled screws, etc.

In the case shown in the second image, I'd be inclined to use a [skewed hanger](http://www.fastenersplus.com/Simpson-4x6-Concealed-Flange-Joist-Hanger-Skewed-Left-Galvanized?gclid=CjwKEAjw7qi7BRCvsr3N58GvsTkSJAA3UzLv1zUip1BGa4vsIGWQzPG_B0AGcLysPavSeryEXwP_cxoC2-bw_wcB) and hang the angled beam on the other two. If your beams actually have the offset shown, things are complicated a bit, but maybe a short third member bolted to the right-hand beam would flush things up in simple fashion.

Comment: Unfortunately it's unclear if some arbitrary fastening scheme would be permitted here. The handout I have says that post top brackets are allowed, and that notched posts with bolts are allowed. With a 6x6 post and 6x beams there's not enough width in the post to make a notch, so that leaves just brackets. The skewed hanger seems like a viable option, though. I guess for the 45 degree corners I can hang the bearing beam over the post just enough to leave room for the hanger.

Comment: The hanger can sit above the post. Notch the hung beam 1/8" if necessary to accommodate.

Comment: Awesome answer +++  @ Isherwood  your suggestion would work in all the states I have worked. ! +

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 posts at the angled corner, one for each of the angled beams and angled to be parallel to the run of the beam.  Miter the beam ends where they join and screw together.

Alternatively you could notch a single post with and angled notch where necessary.  In fact, notching 6x6 posts is a cheaper solution and at least as structurally sound (if not more so).

Comment: The problem with the notched post is there's not much space for the notch even on a 6x6 when using a triple member beam.